# How to make a floated div vertically aligned relative to height of its container

Tags: css, css-float, css-tables

I'm trying to vertically align a floated div that's inside a parent div.  Since the parent div can contain a varying amount of content, I'd like it to be vertically aligned vs. having to set a fixed margin-top on the floated div.  Live example here, where the right arrow you see is in the upper right corner of the gray div but I want it to be vertically centered http://jsbin.com/oriqow/1/

**CSS:**

```
.item { vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 10px; background: #e6e6e6; border-radius: 4px; }
.item > div:not(.arrow) { margin-bottom:10px; }
.arrow { float: right; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="arrow">▶</div>
  <div>Title</div>
  <div>Sub title</div>
  <div>Another potential element here</div>
  <div>And another</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this style to your .arrow class:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -18px;
```

(and remove the float:right; )

And make this to your .item class:

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but you can't know that he needs to have `margin-top: -18px;` without him telling us a specified height. He should have `margin-top: -[half of your div's height];`

Comment: Correct; the arrow that is used is 37px high, so a margin-top of -18px (37/2) has to be applied to be vertically centred.
This because the top-offset of 50% is based on the top-left corner of your element.

Comment: Where did you see 37px though? I see 20px high which is -10px top margin. I know it's different on different browsers, but it shouldn't be THAT different. Are you seeing something that I'm not in his post? Also, he should set it to the div height that he defines himself in the code, rather than basing it on the browser-rendered size (sometimes changes)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/v8f8Q/

```
.item { position:relative; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 10px; background: #e6e6e6; border-radius: 4px; }
.item > div:not(.arrow) { margin-bottom:10px; }
.arrow { position:absolute; top:45%; right:2%; }​
```